# Can the CSS word-wrap: break-word be applied to an <input/> of type text?

Tags: css

Ive applied that css but its not doing anything which isnt what i expected. Im trying to make my input type text break around a heading that comes after it.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualising what effect you're after. `<input type="text" />` is a single-line input, there's no wrapping to be had at all. Aren't you looking for `float` instead?

Comment: do you mean `textarea` ?